# Avoid scheduled executor from creating several instances of a java process

Tags: java, process, exec, runnable, scheduledexecutorservice

I created a scheduledTask that executes a call to an external .jar that creates some xml Files,  I want this to run every 4 minutes. 
Every time the external .jar is run a new instance of it is created but I want it to close the existing one and create a new one instead

basically this is my code :

```
private static void RunInvoiceProcesses(Properties props) {
ScheduledExecutorService executorService =  
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new 
Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c call C:\\creinvoice\\XMLGen\\runxmlgen.bat");


        }
},
15,
240,
TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

//the .bat simply calls java -jar myapp.jar

and that is the one that should only be run one instance at a time. 
every time this runnable is run it calls the bat and a new instance is created by the JVM.

I tried creating an instance of Process outside the executor and doing something like this

```
Process xmlGeneration = null;

  Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
    if (xmlGeneration.stillAlive()){xmlGeneration.Destroy();}
         xmlGeneration= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c call C:\\creinvoice\\XMLGen\\runxmlgen.bat");


        }
}
```

but it seems you can only bring final variables into the runnable, so it's not possible.
Of course I tried researching all I could about this, but if you can at least point me in the right direction of where to look, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I also found that some people bind an instance of an app to a ServerSocket to achieve something similar to what I am trying, but am unsure if that is a safe approach, any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Javadoc

> If any execution of this task
>        * takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions
>        * may start late, but will not concurrently execute.

So you just need to wait for process to finish in your runnable with something like this:

```
Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);
p.waitFor();
```

In this case your `Runnable` will wait for underlying process to finish and because of how `ScheduledThreadPool` works there will be no overlapping executions of your process.

Comment: I just checked that and it seems to be the/a solution to this problem. Thanks a lot!